# Comparing JSON arrays for similar values in typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have 2 JSON object, one is an array of strings and the other is an array of objects.  I would like to check if a value from the string array exists within the object array, and if it does, set a specific value in the object array.

i.e: Given the following object array

```
### Object Array before
[{
   name: 'ABCDE',
   value: 'abcde',
   checked: false
},
{
   name: 'FGHIJ',
   value: 'fghij',
   checked: false
},
{
   name: 'KLMNO'
   value: 'klmno'
   checked: false
}]
```

and given the following string array:

```
[ 'fghij', 'klmno' ]
```

the result should be the following:

```
### Object Array after
[{
   name: 'ABCDE',
   value: 'abcde',
   checked: false
},
{
   name: 'FGHIJ',
   value: 'fghij',
   checked: true
},
{
   name: 'KLMNO'
   value: 'klmno'
   checked: true
}]
```

Comment: The string array isn't one; that is an object array. Should it be `['fghij','klmno']` ?

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
 arr.map( v => Object.assign(v, {checked: stringArray.indexOf(v.value) !== -1 }))
```

`arr` is the original array, `stringArray` contains `['fghij','klmno']`

**edit**: [Typescript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20'ABCDE'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20value%3A%20'abcde'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20checked%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20'FGHIJ'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20value%3A%20'fghij'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20checked%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%2C%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20name%3A%20'KLMNO'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20value%3A%20'klmno'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20checked%3A%20false%0D%0A%7D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20stringArray%20%3D%20%5B'fghij'%2C%20'klmno'%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20res%20%3D%20arr.map(v%20%3D%3E%20Object.assign(v%2C%20%7B%20checked%3A%20stringArray.indexOf(v.value)%20!%3D%3D%20-1%20%7D))%0D%0A%0D%0Awindow.alert(JSON.stringify(res))) demonstrating it

If you do not want the original array to be modified change the `assign` call to `Object.assign({}, v, {checked: stringArray.indexOf(v.value) !== -1 })`

Comment: It works partialy, returning the following: `[ { "checked": false }, { "checked": true }, { "checked": true } ]` - none of the other data was mapped.

Comment: Are you targeting ES6? `Object.assign ` is basically doing a shallow "merge" of two objects but is only available in ES6. If not you must get a polyfill

Comment: The polyfill is there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: I have set-up a Typescript playground so that you can see it running. See edit above

Comment: Thanks, I had an extra parenthesis at the end which caused only checked to return

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to collect the values in an ES6 `Set` object for code clarity and performance reasons.

Basically you have two option here: modify the array in place, or copying it. Example for both:

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'ABCDE',
    value: 'abcde',
    checked: false
}, {
    name: 'FGHIJ',
    value: 'fghij',
    checked: false
}, {
    name: 'KLMNO',
    value: 'klmno',
    checked: false
}];

const toCheck = [ 'fghij', 'klmno' ];


const toCheckSet = new Set(toCheck);

// copying the data
const newData = data.map(obj => ({
    name: obj.name,
    value: obj.value,
    checked: toCheckSet.has(obj.value)
}));
console.log(newData);

// altering in place:
data.forEach(obj => { obj.checked = toCheckSet.has(obj.value); })
console.log(data);
```